# Bootstrap Carousel loop through active storage pictures Rails 6

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I've been trying to add a carousel that can detect images being uploaded and display them accordingly in the carousel. Like if i upload 1 it will only show that, if 2 then so on. I can't seem to really know what to do. i have been trying code after code but it never works. i guess i should loop them somehow but i just cant get it through my head as to what to read to make it happen.

i used this code before wanting to use the carousel but it doenst work if i try to put it inside the carousel

```
 <% (0...@ad.photos.count).each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag(@ad.photos[photo]) %>
  <% end %>
```

and this is a simple carousel

```
 <div class="container my-4">

    <hr class="my-4">

    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
    <div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" data-ride="carousel">
      <!--Slides-->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src=".." alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src=".." alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src=".." alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/.Slides-->
      <!--Controls-->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      <!--/.Controls-->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> <img class="d-block w-100"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="1"><img class="d-block w-100" ></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="2"><img class="d-block w-100" ></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
```

i tried reusing the code into the wrapper but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work. I considered the photos as being saved in Cloudinary, if not, just change the code in the "img" tag to display the photos in the correct way.

```
<% if @ad.photos.size == 1 %>
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= cl_image_path @ad.photos.first.key %>" alt="photo" >

<% elsif @ad.photos.size > 1 %>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <% @ad.photos.size.times do |i| %>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<%= i %>" class="<%= "active" if i.zero? %>"></li>
            <% end %>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <% @ad.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
                <div class="carousel-item <%= "active" if index.zero? %>">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= cl_image_path photo.key %>" alt="<%= index.ordinalize %> image">
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
<% end %>
```